# Historical OpenStreetMap data and dummy lines

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I'm trying to export some historical highway data from OSM  with the following commands:

```
osmium time-filter clipped_greece_history-190715.pbf --overwrite  "${YEAR}-12-31T00:00:00Z" -o "osm${YEAR}.pbf"

# extract specific categories
osmosis \
    --read-pbf file="osm${YEAR}.pbf" \
    --tf accept-ways highway=motorway,trunk,primary,secondary,tertiary,unclassified,residential \
    --used-node \
    --write-pbf "osm${YEAR}_highways.pbf"
```

But I get some dummy(?) lines:
[image]

Am I missing something?
I cannot find an easy way to exclude those lines. Some of them are not straight lines.
[image]